# OSX terminal app error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift, macos

#### In Xcode Version 12.1 (12A7403)

I have a OSX terminal app, used to do audio conversion.

when there is no App Sandbox capability,

[image: 4444]

Xcode tips:

> Simultaneous accesses to 0x100010518, but modification requires
> exclusive access. Previous access (a read) started at convertEr`main +
> 3572 (0x100007354).

here is my code:

```
let outputFileURL: CFURL  = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, "output.aif" as CFString, .cfurlposixPathStyle, false)
Utility.check(error: AudioFileCreateWithURL(outputFileURL,
                                            kAudioFileAIFFType,
                                            &audioConverterSettings.outputFormat,
                                            .eraseFile,
                                            &audioConverterSettings.outputFile),
              operation: "AudioFileCreateWithURL failed");
```

after I added  App Sandbox capability, and I removed all my code

Xcode tips:

[image: 555]

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

#### Very weird

I did it in Objective-C and OK. I can access and write resources without sand box capability.

I think it is an Apple bug.